# Multiple, multi-line equations in amsmath

Tags: amsmath

I am experiencing the following problem. I have multiple equations that need to be aligned and numbered, but some of them are too long to fit into one line.

Here is my small example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\huge Here are my equations:
\begin{align}
 A & = B should be numbered \\
 A & = C another very long equation which must be split at a resaonable place, but still numbered
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't this something for the `multiline` or `split` environments?

Comment: probably... It would be nice to get a definite answer that others could use. I am not sure how to use the "&". To which one does it refer: inner or outer environment? Is this similar to nested tables?

Comment: I am pretty sure there are answers on this already here ... but I am too lazy to look after them ;-)

Comment: Sam here. Except, that my google search did not yield anything. I can write an answer, or let someone else try..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are 3 possibilities, hopefully illustrative. I suppose there are two groups of alignment, and the second group has long equations:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

Here are my equations:

\begin{align}
  \shortintertext{with \texttt{aligned}: }
  A & = B & \text{should be } & \text{ numbered }\\
  A & = C & \text{another very long } & \!\begin{aligned}[t] & \text{ equation which must be split} \\
  & \text{ at a reasonable place,}\\
  & \text{ but still numbered} \end{aligned}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
  \shortintertext{with \texttt{aligned} again: }
  A & = B & \text{should be } & \text{ numbered }\\
  A & = C & \text{another very long } & \!\begin{aligned}[t]  \text{ equation which must be split} &   \\
  \text{ at a reasonable place,} & \\
  \text{ but still numbered} &  \end{aligned}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
  \shortintertext{A variant with \texttt{multlined}: }
  A & = B & \text{should be }        & \text{ numbered }                                            \\
  A & = C & \text{another very long } & \!\begin{multlined}[t]  \text{ equation which must be split} \\
  \text{ at a reasonable place,}\\[-0.8ex]
  \text{ but still numbered}
  \end{multlined}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

As are suggested in @Christian Hupfer comments above

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\huge Here with multlined:
\begin{align}
 A & = B should be numbered \\
 A & = \begin{multlined}[t][0.7\textwidth]
        C + another + very +\\ 
        long + equation + which + \\
        must + bev split + at + \\
        a + resaonable + place, +  \\
        but + still + numbered
        \end{multlined}
\end{align}
or with split
\begin{align}
 A = \; & B should be numbered \\
\begin{split}
 A =\; & C + another + very +\\
   &    long + equation + which + \\
   &    must + bev split + at + \\
   &    a + resaonable + place, +  \\
   &    but + still + numbered
        \end{split}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, I mispelled the name: `multlined` is the correct name ;-) (+1)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I always struggle with its correct spelling too :-)