# Line break within an align-environment

Tags: equations, formatting, align, multline, split

I want to write a long calculation with the align-environment. One of the lines is too long for one line though, so I want it to split into two lines , with the second line right-attached. Example: See picture.
I tried every combination with equation, align, aligned, split, multline, multlined,... I could think of, sadly nothing worked so far. At the moment I solve the problem with `&\hspace + ...`, but I want to have a solution that is independent of the chosen font, margin, etc.
[image: Example]

Here is a more specific example, where I need this function. It is a split cross product and I think that it looks weird if the second part of the cross product is left attached:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        \mathcal{A} &= \int_0^T\int_{K_1}\left[c(\alpha,n)+\alpha|u|^2-\alpha^2(u\cdot(x-x_0))^2\left(|x-x_0|^2+h^2 \right)^{-1} \right]\\
        &\hspace{7.2cm}\times\left[|x-x_0|^2+h^2 \right]^{\alpha}\tau~dx~dt\\
        &\leq K\int_0^T\int_{K_1}\pi~dx~dt
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

I want to replace the `\hspace{7.2cm}` with a margin-independent command.
[image: example2]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Have a look at [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324388/multiple-multi-line-equations-in-amsmath), youn migh find the solutions there quite helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, splitting long equations should always be done with more care from the author. So I always split my equations *manually* to get the desired output.

My preferred solution below uses the following tricks:

1. A `\phantomrel` command which creates a “phantom” relation symbol that occupies the same space as the underlying symbol, thus the `\phantomrel{=}`.
2. A `\hphantom{\int_0^T \int_{K_1}}` that creates a *horizontal* phantom space which serves as indent for the `\times ...` contents.
3. A `\diff` command dedicated for differentials.
4. A `\abs` command dedicated for absolute values, which must be created using `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from the `mathtools` package. This `\abs{...}` has several advantages over `|...|`:

   - Try typing `$|-x|$` and `$\abs{-x}$` to see the wrong spacing of the negative sign in the former expression.
   - You get to enlarge the delimiters by variants `\abs[\big]{-x}`, `\abs[\Big]{-x}`, `\abs[\bigg]{-x}` and `\abs[\Bigg]{-x}`.
   - There is another variant `\abs*{-x}` which extends delimiters automatically (like a `\left` and `\right` pair), but acts like `\mathopen...\mathclose` and not like `\mathinner`, which is better.
5. Please don’t abuse `\left` and `\right`. Sometimes they create delimiters that are too big or too small, and they create `\mathinner`. I used manual sizing throughout your example.

The environments you mentioned work perfectly fine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% For `multlined' and loads `amsmath'
\newcommand*\phantomrel[1]{\mathrel{\phantom{#1}}}% My preferred typesetting
\newcommand*\diff{\mathop{}\!d}% Just in case your editor asks for \mathrm{d}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Using \verb|align*| and \verb|multlined| works fine:
\begin{align*}
A & = \text{something something something} \\
  & = \begin{multlined}[t][10cm]
        \text{something something something anything anything} \\
        + \text{anything anything anything}
      \end{multlined} \\
  & = \text{anything anything anything anything}
\end{align*}
However, I~would typeset as follows instead:
\begin{align*}
A & = \text{something something something} \\
  & = \text{something something something anything} \\
  & \phantomrel{=} {} + \text{anything anything anything anything} \\
  & = \text{anything anything anything anything}
\end{align*}
So your specific example becomes
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{A} & = \int_0^T \int_{K_1}
    \Bigl[ c(\alpha,n) + \alpha\abs{u}^2
           - \alpha^2 \bigl(u\cdot(x-x_0)\bigr)^2
             \bigl(\abs{x-x_0}^2 + h^2\bigr)^{-1} \Bigr] \\
 & \phantomrel{=} \hphantom{\int_0^T \int_{K_1}}
    \times \bigl[\abs{x-x_0}^2 + h^2 \bigr]^\alpha \tau \diff x\diff t \\
 & \leq K \int_0^T \int_{K_1} \pi \diff x\diff t
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: split example]

Comment: Thanks for your response! This just isn't quite what I'm looking for. I had a kind of similar solution before (using hspace in the align-environment instead of multlined plus a parameter). However, I would like to find a solution without a parameter, such that the first line of multlined in your example is left attached, the second line is right attached. So exactly like the multline environment behaves, except for that it is inside of an align environment

Comment: I attached a MWE. I have a lot of those terms in a document where I might need to change the font size or margin width. Would be a lot of work to change each parameter individually after each format change...

Comment: @Carolin Please check my updated answer. ;-)

Comment: Thank you a lot, especially for the 'off-topic' hints. I will study them carefully and try to use them for better latex style. sometimes it is hard to let go of bad habits, if they kind of work :-D

Comment: one more question: what is the advantage of \phantomrel over \phantom ? I tried both and could not find a difference

Comment: @Carolin Try typing `$a=b$\par $a\phantom{=}b$\par $a\phantomrel{=}b$` (the `\par` here forces LaTeX to do a paragraph break, for this illustration only! You should never do this). You should be able to spot the different spacing: In particular, the second line should appear to be shorter. This is because a single `\phantom{=}` is a math ordinary object (`\mathord`), but the shortcut `\phantomrel{=}` forces whatever is inside to be a math relation object (`\mathrel`).

Comment: @Carolin BTW, please notice in the line `\phantomrel{=} {} + \text{...` I used an empty `{}`: This forces the next `+` sign to be a math binary operator (`\mathbin`). Otherwise this “plus” sign would be interpreted as a “positive” sign. On another note, the very reason `$|-x|$` is *wrong* is that TeX thought it was `| minus x |`, i.e., a unary negation is falsely identified as a binary subtraction. But `$\abs{-x}$` has no mistakes.

Comment: Thats pretty interesting! thank you for the example, that made it easy to spot the difference. I searched for a 'guide' how to write in good latex style, but didn't find one so far. I wish I knew all the things with the abs operator, correct spacing and 'bad styles' before I wrote about 100 pages.. :'D

Comment: @Carolin A thorough read of the [User’s Guide for the `amsmath` Package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) is much recommended. If you had more time, you could read the [`mathtools` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/mathtools.pdf) as well (this is where `\abs` comes from). And, trust me, my learning curve of LaTeX is long and painful as well, :-)

Comment: Unfortunately this breaks a little when the equation you're trying to split is a long expression in curly braces (at least with my compiler, where having a hanging \{ inside of \hphantom causes errors). One can just add an extra \} if they're not being too pedantic though.

Comment: @MorganRogers I have not encountered any error when using `\hphantom{\{}` in equations. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 2):

A few suggestions; the text before each of them should tell you what I'd prefer. `;-)`

Another suggestion: don't use `~` for spacing differentials, but `\,`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example

\begin{document}

The ugly:
\begin{flalign*}
\mathcal{A}
&= \mathrlap{\int_0^T\int_{K_1}
     \bigl[
       c(\alpha,n)+\alpha|u|^2-\alpha^2(u\cdot(x-x_0))^2(|x-x_0|^2+h^2)^{-1}
     \bigr]} &\\
&&&\mathllap{{}\times\bigl[\,|x-x_0|^2+h^2\bigr]^{\alpha}\tau\,dx\,dt}\\
&\leq \mathrlap{K\int_0^T\int_{K_1}\pi\,dx\,dt}
\end{flalign*}

The bad:
\begin{flalign*}
\quad\mathcal{A}
&= \mathrlap{\int_0^T\int_{K_1}
     \bigl[
       c(\alpha,n)+\alpha|u|^2-\alpha^2(u\cdot(x-x_0))^2(|x-x_0|^2+h^2)^{-1}
     \bigr]} &\\
&&&\mathllap{{}\times\bigl[\,|x-x_0|^2+h^2\bigr]^{\alpha}\tau\,dx\,dt}\quad\\
&\leq \mathrlap{K\int_0^T\int_{K_1}\pi\,dx\,dt}
\end{flalign*}

The good:
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{A}
&= \int_0^T\int_{K_1}
   \begin{aligned}[t]
     &\bigl[
        c(\alpha,n)+\alpha|u|^2-\alpha^2(u\cdot(x-x_0))^2(|x-x_0|^2+h^2)^{-1}
      \bigr] \\
     &\qquad\times\bigl[\,|x-x_0|^2+h^2\bigr]^{\alpha}\tau\,dx\,dt
   \end{aligned}
\\[2ex]
&\leq K\int_0^T\int_{K_1}\pi\,dx\,dt
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The `showframe` package makes the text block evident by drawing a frame around it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! If it is more common to kind of 'center' the second part of the cross product, then I will just do that, which also solves my fontsize-independent problem :)